# Adjust cell width in grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView (grouped style) and I would like to adjust the width of the cells such that there is less padding on the sides. I want the cells to occupy the full width of the table view (like the plain style tableview).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't with the grouped style of the UITableView. You could however use the plain style, and create your own view to show as the cell, just like the grouped view.

Comment: I'll give that a try later and see how it looks. Thanks.