# Set the width of an grouped cell in Xcode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Am fooling around with this question a couple of days now but no progress. What i want to do is quite simple i think:

I have an image of 320x60 which i use in the plain TableView which works oke as those cells take up the entire width (320) of the screen. The grouped cells in a TableView are 300 wide and have insets/margins left of 10 on the left and the right.

Can i somehow remove those insets/margins and let the grouped cell be 320 wide? I tried setting the content inset left to -10. That does "remove" the left margin but then it's still only 300 wide. Also tried editing the XML of the storyboard (I'm working with iOS 5 - Storyboards) but no joy.

This similar question here got answered as no it's not possible, hopfully something changed in 2+ years!:
[Adjust cell width in grouped UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221873/adjust-cell-width-in-grouped-uitableview)

PS i want to alter the width as the background images contain nice shadows, I've read that exesive use of shadows could mean performance issues. Also the shadow's are 5px extra around the border so that would mean -10px wide if I use the standard width.

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An **untidy solution** is to make the table view 340 pixels wide, and 10 pixels off the left edge of the screen.

A **solution that involves changing properties of private classes** is to make a `UITableViewCell` subclass, and override its `layoutSubviews` method.  When I log the subviews, I find these:

```
"<UIGroupTableViewCellBackground: 0x95246b0; frame = (9 0; 302 45); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x95226b0>>",
"<UITableViewCellContentView: 0x92332d0; frame = (10 0; 300 43); layer = <CALayer: 0x9233310>>",
"<UIView: 0x95248c0; frame = (10 0; 300 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x951f140>>"
```

What happens if we take those subviews and fill the entire bounds available?

```
- (void)layoutSubviews;
{
    // By default the cell bounds fill the table width, but its subviews (containing the opaque background and cell borders) are drawn with padding.
    CGRect bounds = [self bounds];

    // Make sure any standard layout happens.
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // Debugging output.
    NSLog(@"Subviews = %@", [self subviews]);
    for (UIView *subview in [self subviews])
    {
        // Override the subview to make it fill the available width.
        CGRect frame = [subview frame];
        frame.origin.x = bounds.origin.x;
        frame.size.width = bounds.size.width;
        [subview setFrame:frame];
    }
}
```

At this particular moment, on the iOS 5.1 simulator, this works.  Now, some future version of iOS may restructure these classes, causing this method to catastrophically mangle the table layout.  Your app could be rejected for changing the properties of UITableViewCellContentView... even though you're only modifying its frame.  So, how much do you need to have your cells fill the table width?

Comment: From a designers perspective it's a must. If it doesn't seem possible in a "tidy" manner we'll keep the width and alter the background to fit.. If there are no other options at the time I will mark this as the best answer, thanks!

Comment: This is awesome! I have been looking for this hack. I want a plain TableView but don't want the section headers to be sticky to the top. The only way to do this was to switch to grouped mode, which causes the UITableView to override the cell background, and THEN add this fix to resize the cells. HATE Apple for not giving developers freedom and making us do there hacks to customize.

Answer (score 0):

You can the UITableView's Leading and Trailing Space constraints in the Size Inspector which is accessible via the Storyboard. I'm not sure when this was added, but setting the Leading Space Constraint to -10 and the Trailing Space Constraint to 10 will make the cells full width.

Comment: I don't see those options being enabled when I select a table view within the storyboard.