# Increasing the width of UITableViewCell in a grouped TableView layout

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to get rid of the cell margin on the left and right of a set of cells within a group.

I have looked around and have found [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070854/set-the-width-of-an-grouped-cell-in-xcode)
but this seems like it could cause plenty of problems down the track.

I also tried changing the cell.indentationWidth and cell.indentationLevel but these seem to change the indentation within the cell, not the cell itself.

Is there an Apple approved way of changing these cells to stretch the width of the Tableview??

Thank you in advance, your help is much appreciated.

Scott

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing. add label or any other control in this and then add that in your `UITableviewcell`.

Then you can give whatever format you want according to your need.